# Principal Curvature

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Find the principal curvature at the vertices of the hyperboloid with two sheets $$\frac {x^2}{a^2}-\frac {y^2}{b^2}-\frac {z^2}{c^2}=1$$
Can someone help me with this problem ??

Comment: Can you start by parametrizing the surface conveniently? As a hint, start with $x=a\cosh u$, $y=b\sinh u\cos v$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Ok so after Parametrizing, what I got is: $$x=a\sqrt{1+\frac{u^2}{c^2}} \cos v, \ \ \ y=b\sqrt{1+\frac{u^2}{c^2}} \cos v, \ \ \ z=u $$ Now what will I do next?

Comment: I would leave it in terms of cosh and sinh, myself. Now compute the first and second fundamental forms at the vertices ... [Note that I carefully chose the variables to get the rotational symmetry with $y/b$ and $z/c$.]

Comment: @TedShifrin I can find the First Fundamental form but I dont know how to find second because I couldnt find any helping material for that topic

Comment: It's in all the books. You can look at my own text (freely downloadable .pdf linked in my profile). But make sure you use a correct (and reasonable) parametrization. Yours isn't right.

Comment: @TedShifrin The coefficients of first form are $E=1+\frac{a^2u^2}{u^2+c^2}, \  \ F=0 , \ \ G=a^2(1+\frac{u^2}{c^2})$

Comment: @TedShifrin So what will be the correct parametrization ?

Comment: @TedShifrin And what will be the next step after finding first and second form?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58018/discussion-between-hitman-and-ted-shifrin).

Comment: @TedShifrin Sir can you please answer my questions ?

Comment: @TedShifrin In the equation of $y$, I wrote above, it is $\sin v $ instead of $\cos v$

Comment: @TedShifrin What is $z$ in the parameterization you wrote above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

calculate second fundamental matrix.
$$II = \begin{bmatrix} X_{yy}\cdot n & X_{yz}\cdot n \\ X_{zy}\cdot n & X_{zz}\cdot n \end{bmatrix},$$
$${x } =\sqrt{\frac {y^2a^2}{b^2}+\frac {z^2a^2}{c^2}+a^2}$$
$$f(y,z)=\sqrt{\frac {y^2a^2}{b^2}+\frac {z^2a^2}{c^2}+a^2}$$
then finding out the  $X_{yy}=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}$...
and n is the unit normal vector

[image: fgz]

Comment: Can you please explain how you get to this answer?

Comment: How can I find $n$ ? And what will be the next step after finding the above matrix?