# Finding the vertex of a two-sheet-hyperboloid

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, analytic-geometry

> Find the normal curvature of the hyperboloid
> $$\frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{b^2} - \frac{z^2}{c^2} = 1$$ at the vertex of the hyperboloid.

I know the rest of the [work](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260314/principal-curvature), but how to find the vertex of such hyperboloid? The problem says it is two-sheets-hyperboloid (or two surface). Should I find the minimum value that $x$ can take (I guess this from the picture attached) or what?

[image]

Comment: You can consider the hyperbolic "cross-sections" of the surface with each of the coordinate planes:  $ \ z = 0 \ $ produces $$\frac{x^2}{a^2} \ -  \ \frac{y^2}{b^2}  \ = \ 1 $$ and $ \ y = 0 \ $ gives us $$ \frac{x^2}{a^2} \  - \  \frac{z^2}{c^2} =  1 \ \ , $$ which together tell us that the "vertices" of the hyperboloid lie at $ \ ( \pm a \ , \ 0 \ , \ 0 \ ) \ \ . $  There is no intersection with $ \ x = 0 \ \ , $ as $$  - \frac{y^2}{b^2} \ - \  \frac{z^2}{c^2} \  = \  1 \ $$ is not possible for real numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the equation of hyperboloid is $\dfrac{x^2}{a^2} - \dfrac{y^2}{b^2} - \dfrac{z^2}{c^2} = 1$. It is a hyperboloid of two sheets with x-axis passing through them. At the points that x-axis intersects both sheets of the hyperboloid is being referred to vertices here. So we plug in $y = z = 0$ and that gives us $x = \pm a$.

Comment: Thank you! Could you help me with my question in this [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4173429/finding-the-vertex-of-a-two-sheet-hyperboloid/4173433#comment8646009_4173433)

Comment: That parametrization is not correct as the hyperboloid in question is along x-axis. It should rather be $(a \cosh(v), b \cos u \sinh(v), c \sin u \sinh(v))$

Comment: Then $v = 0, u \in \mathbb R$ for $(a,0,0)$?

Comment: Yes at $v = 0, \cosh (v) = 1, \sinh (v) = 0$ and you have same parametrization with $x = -a\cosh (v)$ for the other sheet

Comment: Great, thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

I've never heard about vertex of a hyperboloid, but I suppose that, here, it means the points $(\pm a,0,0)$. In fact, these points belong to the hyperboloid, and if $(x,y,z)$ is such that $|x|<a$, then$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}-\frac{z^2}{c^2}\leqslant\frac{x^2}{a^2}<1$$and therefore $(x,y,z)$ does not belong to hyperbolod.

Comment: Isn't the last inequality in the other direction, sorry?

Comment: But I got you $$\frac{x^2}{a^2} = 1 + \text{positive} \\ x^2 = a^2(1+\text{positive}) \ge a^2 \\ x \in (-\infty, -a]\cup [a, +\infty)$$ right?

Comment: The last equality is $\frac{x^2}{a^2}<1$, which is true, since $|x|<a$.

Comment: I see now. Thank you! How can I find this point with parametric equation $x = \sinh v \cos \theta, ~ y = b\sinh v \sin \theta, ~ z = \pm \cosh v$? $z$ seems to be always non-zero. I got the parametrization from Wiki